# Passing arguments to spring cloud tasks

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I used composed task runner to run two tasks. These two tasks refer to simple spring boot applications. I want to pass launch time arguments to the two child tasks. The arguments are different for each child tasks. I read that properties can be sent to individual tasks. Is there a way to do the same for arguments ?

Reference task : composed-task-runner --graph = task1 && task2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass arguments as well as properties for the individual child tasks.

The usage for this is documented in SCDF documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_launching_a_composed_task).

Comment: I used Composed-task-arguments to achieve this and it worked.Thanks.